# Hide record from continuous form if checkbox is marked in query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a continuous Form with records, the records contain a yes/no. So if the checkbox in the form is marked I want the record to be hidden from the form next time you open it, but it does not seem to work.

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
If Me.Checkbox = False Then
Me.Checkbox.Visble = True
Else
Me.Checkbox.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a *Boolean* field named `Hidden` having a *DefaultValue* of `False` in the table and, in the form, bind this field to the checkbox.

Then, when opening the form, filter on `[Hidden] = False`.

Comment: Thanks I will try that but I've also tried: Query for the check box, criteria: "True" or -1 but then messes up because there's many records also in other forms. Edit: Creating a new query fixed it.